# vba Sort by multiple criteria and copy values to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hello again guys I have another tough problem for you, well may not be tough for you but it is for me. So I have one sheet with all of my data and I would like to sort by the first 3 conditions (Reject, Other, & year) Would be nice to be able to pick months too. Once the data is filtered I have it copied and sorted on another sheet so I can do some other functions and generate a table showing amount of times the vendor was rejected. There may be a simpler way to do this but currently this is the way I slapped together. If you have any other suggestions I would like to hear them.Code fails at the year sort. I keep getting all of the data from the other sheet

```
 ''Generates defect list
Sub Make_Defect_List_Yearly()
    Const REJECTED_COL = 8  'Column H (DISPOSITIO)
    Const DATE_COL = 13
    Dim shAD As Worksheet, shVP As Worksheet
    Dim adRng As Range, vpRng As Range, headers() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, fCell As Range, lCell As Range
    Dim flg As Byte, LastRow As Long, flag As Boolean, i

    Set shAD = Worksheets("AllData")
    Set shVP = Worksheets("VendorProblems")
    lr = shAD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("VendorProblems").UsedRange.ClearContents

'Copy VendorProblems to shVP --------------------------
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    shAD.AutoFilterMode = False

    With shAD.UsedRange
        Set adRng = FilterWS(.Columns(DATE_COL), "2017")
        If Not adRng Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.CountLarge > 2 Then
                Set vpRng = shVP.Cells(shVP.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy vpRng
            End If
        End If
    End With

    With shAD.UsedRange
        Set adRng = FilterWS(.Columns(REJECTED_COL), "Reject")
        If Not adRng Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.CountLarge > 2 Then
                Set vpRng = shVP.Cells(shVP.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy vpRng
            End If
        End If
    End With

    With shAD.UsedRange
        Set adRng = FilterWS(.Columns(REJECTED_COL), "Other")
        If Not adRng Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.CountLarge > 2 Then
                Set vpRng = shVP.Cells(shVP.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy vpRng
            End If
        End If
    End With



    shAD.AutoFilterMode = False
'shVP.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
'Sort shVP ----------------------------------------------------
    Set vpRng = shVP.UsedRange.Columns(11)
    With shVP.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange shVP.UsedRange
        .SortFields.Add Key:=vpRng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
'Remove blanks from shVP --------------------------------------
    With shVP.UsedRange
        shVP.AutoFilterMode = False
        If Len(shVP.Cells(1)) = 0 Then shVP.Cells(1) = "Header": flg = 1
        Set vpRng = FilterWS(shVP.UsedRange.Columns(11), "=")
        If Not vpRng Is Nothing Then
            Set vpRng = shVP.UsedRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If .Cells.Count > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If flg = 1 Then shVP.Cells(1).EntireRow.Delete
        shVP.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Copys qty recieved to amnt rejected if amt rejected is blank
    With shVP
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cel In .Range("G2:G" & lr)             'loop through each cell in Column
            If (cel.Value) = "" Then                    'check Command Name
                Set fCell = cel.Offset(0, -3)           'set first cell to be copied in fCell
                Set lCell = cel.Offset(0, 0)
                lCell = fCell
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
'Sorts data alphabetically by vendor
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    shVP.Activate
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:P").Activate 'old line a118
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .WrapText = False
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    shVP.Range("A1").Select

    ' Array of header labels
    headers() = Array("Warehouse", "Inspection Type", "ItemID", "QtyReceived", "UOM", "Sample::Sample", "DefectFound", _
                      "Disposition", "PurchOrder", "DISTRIBUTOR", "Manufacturer", "Remarks", "Date", "Cost", "RejectCat", "Date")
    ' Row to insert
    shVP.Activate
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        With shVP
            For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
                .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
            Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Where does the code fail and what is the error?

Comment: Code fails at the year sort. I keep getting all of the data from the other sheet.

Comment: Please add that description to the Original post using [edit]

Comment: Just did thanks and sorry.